# Find right line of code by Regex and replace text in it jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have two lines of javascript code at a Html body.

```
<script text="javascript">
    Muse.Utils.initWidget('#widgetu94', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) { return new WebPro.Widget.Form(elem, {validationEvent:'submit',errorStateSensitivity:'high',fieldWrapperClass:'fld-grp',formSubmittedClass:'frm-sub-st',formErrorClass:'frm-subm-err-st',formDeliveredClass:'frm-subm-ok-st',notEmptyClass:'non-empty-st',focusClass:'focus-st',invalidClass:'fld-err-st',requiredClass:'fld-err-st',ajaxSubmit:true}); });/* #widgetu94 */
    Muse.Utils.initWidget('#widgetu386', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) { return new WebPro.Widget.Form(elem, {validationEvent:'submit',errorStateSensitivity:'high',fieldWrapperClass:'fld-grp',formSubmittedClass:'frm-sub-st',formErrorClass:'frm-subm-err-st',formDeliveredClass:'frm-subm-ok-st',notEmptyClass:'non-empty-st',focusClass:'focus-st',invalidClass:'fld-err-st',requiredClass:'fld-err-st',ajaxSubmit:true}); });/* #widgetu386 */
</script>
```

I need to change text `ajaxSubmit:true` to `ajaxSubmit:false` only for the second line `Muse.Utils.initWidget('#widgetu386'...`

I've tried to use this code

```
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('ajaxSubmit:true', 'ajaxSubmit:false');
</script>
```

But after that all of `ajaxSubmit`are gonna to `false`.
Maybe I need more Regural Expression?

```
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/MagicRegExp/, 'ajaxSubmit:false');
</script>
```

I just want find it by '#widgetu386'
Please help me. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You use the id of an element to make changes to that specific element. I have never used  Muse.Utils.initWidget() personally, but I am assuming that the first paramter of the function is the element id.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("#widgetu386").innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById("#widgetu386").innerHTML.replace(
             'ajaxSubmit:true', 
             'ajaxSubmit:false'
        );
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I think to use getElementByID is not good idea, because it finds a div with id of widgetu386. But I need to find only one line of code.
Thanks for trying.:)

Comment: Yes, get element by id finds an element with an id of  "widgetu386". Just give the your "Muse.Utils.initWidget" the id of "widgetu386". I don't understand what your problem is. Can you not give your "Muse.Utils.initWidget" an id?

Comment: No, I can't. Because this is an adobe muse. And I can't modify this line of code.